# How to handle CSV with variable columns per row

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got a file that has a header row with a fixed number of labels and rows of variable length. The last column has a field that should really be a sublist of items, but this list is treated as a continuum of columns.

Example:

```
Name, Address, Telephone
"Bob Smith", "123 main st", "111-111-1111"
"Jon Smith", "123 main st", "111-111-1111", "222-222-2222"
```

I ultimately want to iterate over the sublist, in this case telephone #'s.

I've tried using csv dictreader but it drops the extra columns.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Always good to post code to show an attempt. Pandas has awesome excel tools.

Comment: use some other delimiter instead of a comma in a value. as soon as csv encounters a comma, it splits. that's' the way it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `DictReader`.  Use the standard `reader` and tuple assignment syntax:

Code:

```
import csv

with open('test.csv') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    next(r) # skip header

    # Note this assigns the 3rd and remaining columns to 'telephone' as a list.
    for name,addr,*telephone in r:
        print(f'name:     {name}')
        print(f'address:  {addr}')
        for i,phone in enumerate(telephone,1):
            print(f'Phone #{i}: {phone}')
        print()
```

test.csv:

```
Name,Address,Telephone
"Bob Smith","123 main st","111-111-1111"
"Jon Smith","123 main st","111-111-1111","222-222-2222"
```

Output:

```
name:     Bob Smith
address:  123 main st
Phone #1: 111-111-1111

name:     Jon Smith
address:  123 main st
Phone #1: 111-111-1111
Phone #2: 222-222-2222
```

Comment: This looks great, however I get an error on the asterisk *telephone.

Comment: @yanir FYI I used Python 3.6, but I have Python 3.3 installed and it also has the feature.  I'm not sure when it was added.

Comment: @yanir [PEP 3132](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) describes the feature and it was implemented in Python 3.0.

Comment: @yanir If that tripped you up, you'll also want Python 3.6 for the [f-strings (See PEP 0498)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498) in the example.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I was on 2.7. I installed 3.7 and it works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in [`DictReader` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader):

> If a row has more fields than `fieldnames`, the remaining data is put in a list and stored with the fieldname specified by `restkey` (which defaults to `None`).

All you must do is pass the `restkey` parameter and all your extra values will go there.

```
with open('yourfile.csv') as f:
    cf = csv.DictReader(f, restkey='extra')
    for row in cf:
        print(row)
```

will print

```
{"Name": "Bob Smith", "Address": "123 main st", "Telephone": "111-111-1111"}
{"Name": "Jon Smith", "Address": "123 main st", "Telephone": "111-111-1111", "extra": ["222-222-2222"]}
```